# PHP foreach loop overwrites all items with last record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I am trying to update a mysql table and I don't know why but all records are filled in with the last entry.

Here is my PHP code:

```
[...]

if (isset($_POST['update'])){

$doorNumber = $_POST['doorNumber']; //array
$doorDescription = $_POST['doorDescription']; //array

//update data
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


foreach($doorNumber as $key => $val){
  $door = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE doors SET number = ?, description = ? WHERE acc_id = ?");
  $door->execute(array($doorNumber[$key], $doorDescription[$key], $id));
}

Database::disconnect();
header('Location: index.php');

[...]
```

and the following is the related html:

```
[...]

<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-uppercase">
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Door #</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                        
                <?php
                    foreach ($rooms as $row){
                        echo '<tr class="text-left text-capitalize">';
                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked"</td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="doorNumber[]" name="doorNumber[]" value=' .$row['number']. '></td>';
                        echo '<td><textarea rows="1" class="form-control" id="doorDescription[]" name="doorDescription[]">' .$row['description']. '</textarea></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
[...]
```

The table is within a form taking records from a mysql database through a $_GET['id'] request (thus setting a value for the variable $id). Whenever I update the records, on submit (i.e. $_POST['update']) the table is updated alright but all records will be equal to the last input.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your `form` tag wraps all the rows within table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html table lists all doors and door description belonging to an acc_id, then each of the update statements update all door numbers and descriptions belonging to an account because in the where criteria only the acc_id is provided.

If you want to maintain door numbers separately, then you have to include them in the where criteria as well **with their original value** (assuming that you cannot have duplicate door numbers for a given account):

```
UPDATE doors SET number = ?, description = ? WHERE acc_id = ? and number=?
```

I would add a hidden control to the html form:

`echo '<input type="hidden" name="originalnumber[]" value="' .$row['number']. '"';`

I would add a new array:

```
$originaldoorNumber = $_POST['originalnumber']; //array
```

The sql would be executed in the following way:

```
$door->execute(array($doorNumber[$key], $doorDescription[$key], $id, $originaldoorNumber[$key]))
```

Comment: Shadow, thank you very much for your suggestion. That actually did the trick! Also thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: In this case pls mark the answer as accepted so that other viewers of this question will know that the question has been solved.